# Android Force Close

Tags: android

In my application, whenever I got some crash it shows Force Close the application. If i click force its automatically restarting the application from the page it got crashed and it shows some malfunctioned activities, Invalid Data and No record... Can you anyone please help to handle this force close, probably like when ever the user clicks that force close it should completely kill the application and the user can relaunch himself to avoid that corrupted data cuz of the crash.

Comment: You should fix the cause of force close instead of modifying standard system behavior.

Comment: no code, no error log how do you think we supposed to help you? my imagination in some case can be very limited :) and this is one of them.

Comment: Each for close will populate your logs with a stacktrace. That should be sufficient for you to determine where the error is. Try to avoid the force close at all times.

Comment: Please provide the logcat output when force close occurs

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you can do if you don't want to properly handle the error that causes the force close is to register a [global uncaught exception handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html). This allows you to catch all Exceptions that you don't have caught anywhere else. Maybe this helps you to recover from such situations. At least you could implement there a log function or something similar.

However I would recommend to try to fix the error in the first place in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Force closes in Android can have many different reasons. It's hard to know the reason for your specific problem since we don't get a lot of information. One problem could be that your data partition is full or almost full. Checkout this guide: [Android force close solution](http://rightinfonow.com/android-force-close-fc-problemsissues-solution)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can completely control/handle **ForceClose Dialog** ! so it doesn't show up to user.

Use [ACRA - Application Crash Report for Android](http://code.google.com/p/acra/)  to collect Crash generated by app. Once you integrate it with your app, if any crash occurs user won't see FORCE CLOSE dialog, instead you can show your CUSTOM ERROR message.

It turns out to be better user experience. let me know if you need more info.
Good luck :)